# Can bracketing commas contain incomplete sentences when introduced by although, though, even though, because, etc.?

Tags: punctuation, commas

According to this university [site](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/bracketing) (section dedicated to bracketing commas):

> There are a number of common words which typically introduce weak
>   interruptions containing **complete sentences**. Among the commonest of
>   these are although, though, even though, because, since , after,
>   before, if, when and whenever.

Example from the site:

> Columbus is usually credited with discovering America, even though **the
>   Vikings had preceded him by several centuries.**

The author says weak interruptions *typically* contain complete sentences. So I wonder if, according to this rule, you can use incomplete sentences as well. Example:

> She'd never let anyone hurt him, even if **that meant sacrificing her
>   life.**

I wonder if by *typically* the author is implying that sometimes these interruptions are not complete sentences.

Comment: They are not sentences, complete or incomplete. A sentence commences with a capital letter and ends with a terminal point. In your first example "even though the Vikings had preceded him by several centuries" is a concessive adjunct, and in the second "even if that meant sacrificing her life" is a conditional adjunct.

Comment: BillJ - The author clearly means 'independent clauses', and is trying to avoid linguistic jargon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
That meant sacrificing her life.
```

is a perfectly good sentence, or independent clause!  So this is not a weak interruption with a dependent clause.

But it can and often does happen.

Here are two examples of weak interruptions which have dependent clauses (incomplete sentences):

```
Apples, which are my favorite fruit, are the main ingredient in this recipe.
My friend Allan, the baker, give me his secret brownies recipe.
```

It can even happen with those introductory phrases:

```
My shoes, although old and worn, are still quite comfortable.
At nine in the evening, after dining, the guests retired to the lounge.
```